# AutoMapper - How to map to a value in a nested type - which could be null?

Tags: c#, automapper

This is probably a simple answer, but i'm just starting to get the hand of AutoMapper.

Anyway, i have a domain object like this:

```
public class User
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public FacebookUser FacebookUser { get; set; }
}
```

And a ViewModel like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public long FacebookUniqueId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's what i have in my AutoMapper configuration:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User,UserViewModel>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.FacebookUniqueId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FacebookUser.FacebookUniqueId))
```

But it throws an exception when the `FacebookUser` object is null, which is to be expected.

How do i tell AutoMapper:

> Map UserViewModel.FacebookUniqueId to User.FacebookUser.FacebookUniqueId, except for when it's null, then use `0`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FacebookUser == null ? 0 : src.FacebookUser.FacebookUniqueId)
```

Yikes, if I had just checked if the first idea worked, thought the `MapFrom` method only took an expression that pointed to a property to resolve it that way...

Comment: It threw a object ref error on `src.FacebookUser.FacebookUniqueId`, since `src.FacebookUser` is null - don't know why it didn't for you. Anyway, adding the null substitute did the trick - cheers!

Comment: Actually, it still throws the error - i thought it worked because i did a build and my page rendered properly. But when i ran it debug mode, it threw the exception again on the same line. Guess AutoMapper swallows the exceptions. So i think that particular statement needs the null check - but how?

Comment: now it should work. I had that at first and thought it wouldn't work, but apperently, it does. Sorry I didn't test it first.

Comment: yep, that's what i figured, old school nullcheck. I was hoping AutoMapper had it's own smart method to do this. Oh well, this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided works on the latest Automapper. I investigated the sources a little and found the following code:

```
try
{
    var result = _method((TSource)source.Value);

    return source.New(result, MemberType);
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
    return source.New(null, MemberType);
}
```

As you can see now Automapper catches all the Null exceptions while resolving chain mappings. The following test is green:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AutomapperChainingMappingTest
{
    [Test]
    public void ChainMapping_NullProperty_DefaultValueSet()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
                  .ForMember(x => x.FacebookUniqueId, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.FacebookUser.FacebookUniqueId));

        var source = new User();
        var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(source);

        Assert.AreEqual(model.FacebookUniqueId, default(long));
    }
}

public class User
{
    public FacebookUser FacebookUser { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public long FacebookUniqueId { get; set; } 
}

public class FacebookUser
{
    public long? FacebookUniqueId { get; set; }
}
```